# Field `Struct` in `where` does not exist in the model source in query

Tags: elixir, ecto

Having an issue using `has_many` and `belongs_to`, I have these two models:

```
  @primary_key {:guid, :integer, []}
  schema "characters" do
    field :name, :string
    field :race, :integer
    field :class, :integer
    field :gender, :integer
    field :level, :integer
    field :xp, :integer
    field :money, :integer
    field :online, :integer
    field :totaltime, :integer
    field :leveltime, :integer
    field :rest_bonus, :float
    field :is_logout_resting, :integer
    field :honor_highest_rank, :integer
    field :honor_standing, :integer
    field :stored_honor_rating, :float
    field :stored_dishonorable_kills, :integer
    field :stored_honorable_kills, :integer
    field :health, :integer
    field :power1, :integer
    field :power2, :integer
    field :power3, :integer
    field :power4, :integer
    field :power5, :integer
    belongs_to :account, Pugit.Account, references: :id
  end
```

And this Account model

```
 schema "account" do
    field :username, :string
    field :sha_pass_hash, :string
    field :gmlevel, :integer, default: 0
    field :sessionkey, :string
    field :v, :string
    field :s, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :joindate, Ecto.DateTime
    field :last_ip, :string, default: "0.0.0.0"
    field :failed_logins, :integer, default: 0
    field :locked, :integer, default: 0
    field :last_login, Ecto.DateTime
    field :active_realm_id, :integer, default: 0
    field :expansion, :integer, default: 0
    field :mutetime, :integer, default: 0
    field :locale, :integer, default: 0

    has_many :characters, PugitWow.Character, foreign_key: :account
  end
```

I'm trying to run this query:

```
Pugit.AccountRepo.all(Pugit.Account) |> Pugit.CharRepo.preload([:characters])
```

The only big difference here is that maybe I'm trying to preload from a different repo (other database)

But I get this error:

```
** (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:320: field `Pugit.Character.account` in `where` does not exist in the model source in query:

from c in Pugit.Character,
  where: c.account in ^[1, 2, 3, 4, 21],
  order_by: [asc: c.account]

    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1473: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1151: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
      (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:91: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
      (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:15: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
```

Any information would be great thanks

The Primary Key for my `characters` table is `guid`

The Foreign Key for my `characters` table is `account`

The Primary Key for my `account` table is `id`

Comment: Why do you have `define_fields: false` in `belongs_to :account`? Does this work if you remove that?

Comment: @Dogbert No it does not sadly, sorry I added that when trying to fool around with trying to get it to work

Comment: Does the `characters` table in your database have `account` field or `account_id`?

Comment: @Dogbert See my edit at the very bottom of my main question

Comment: Try `belongs_to :account, Pugit.Account, references: :id, foreign_key: :account` but I'm not sure if you can have the foreign key be same as the relationship.

Comment: Are you still getting the exact same error after removing `define_fields: false`?

Comment: @Dogbert It seems to work if I change `belongs_to :account` to `belongs_to :accounts` and add the `foreign_key: :account`, it will error if I try to name the foreign key and the field name the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `account` association uses the same name as the field for the foreign key, `account`. Rename that field to `account_id`, and then use this as your association:

```
belongs_to :account, Pugit.Account
```